# Downloading file from GCP is too Slow using C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

We are trying to download a file from GCP bucket console , but the performance is really slow. Even for a 50 MB file it takes around 2 to 3 minutes, that is also varying at a wide range.we are using storageclient downloadobjects method

We have a already working code for GCP Upload that uploads GBs of file at a faster rate. Is there a particular issue when it comes to Download.

We are using a C# code for both upload and download.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GoogleCredentials gcpCreds = new GoogleCredentials()
        {
            private_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----PrivateKey-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
            client_email = "client_email",
            type = "service_account"
        };

        var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromJson(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gcpCreds));

        // var credentials= GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
        var storage = StorageClient.CreateAsync(credentials).Result;
        string localPath, directoryPath, localFileName, objectName, bucketName;
        directoryPath = "localpathstring";
        objectName = "SourceFileName";
        localFileName = objectName;
        localPath = directoryPath + "\\" + localFileName;
       bucketName="bucketName";

       FileStream fs = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        //Code to download with progress bar
        DownloadObjectOptions option = new DownloadObjectOptions();
        using (fs)
        {
            var progress = new Progress<IDownloadProgress>(
                 p => Console.WriteLine($"bytes: {p.BytesDownloaded}, status: {p.Status},"));
            storage.DownloadObject(bucketName, objectName, fs, option, progress);
            }
     }
```

Comment: You haven't posted any code so how can people guess what's wrong? It's not C# that's slow

Comment: `we are using storageclient downloadobjects method` that's not code

Comment: In any case if you have only 1 upload but 1000 downloads on the same line, downloads will be slow. At the very least use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what's actually going on. Perhaps there are a lot of retries? Or the code forgets to close download streams and quickly hits the concurrent connection limit? Or your ISP/network admin may have restricted *your* connection?

Comment: Code has been added

Comment: Using the wording "slow" means nothing. Use facts like my Internet connection speed is X, I can download from Y at Z. My program downloads at A. Provide details so that we can help you. Downloading a 50 MB in 180 seconds file is 2.2 Mbit/sec. Depending on your Internet connection, distance to the source and network utilization, these may be great numbers, or not.

Answer (score 0):

The results in your download speed does not seem so strange, at all, for me. Cloud Storage has a mechanism on going that makes the bigger files to be downloaded faster than the smaller ones. If you will try to download 10 GB file, for example, you will see that the performance will increase considerably.

For this 50MB download use case I think there are not a lot of improvements to be made, but in general, a good way of improving your downloads overall speed is to find a balance between the number of requests you make and the size of them. You can find a nice article about improving GCS performances [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/optimizing-your-cloud-storage-performance-google-cloud-performance-atlas).

Moreover, as some [experiments](https://medium.com/@duhroach/gcs-read-performance-of-large-files-bd53cfca4410) were made, better performances can be achieve by using [gsutil tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil), rather than simple HTTP request.